# How to migrate heroku rails app to the same app on new host?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, heroku

I need to switch my rails app from Heroku to my new host on Linode.
I need to address the following concerns and would appreciate some advice

1) How to migrate the data from Heroku to my new Linode host?

2) How to redirect the Heroku domain from myapp.herokuapp.com to my_new_host.com ?

I need to achieve the above as simultaneously as possible so that new data is not lost

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Assuming you're running PostGres on your Linode host then you will simply need to backup your on Heroku and then restore it into Heroku (pgbackups). There are other options - You could use `heroku db:pull` to pull it down from Heroku into your local database and then transfer than to Linode. Another option would to be use the Heroku gem on your linode server to pull the data directly from the heroku app into the linode database.
2. You can only redirect on Heroku using code, so you would have to push up an app that does a redirect (rack_rewrite) to your new host.
3. You'll want to put your application on Heroku into maintenance mode on Heroku. Perform the data transfer via which ever mechanism you choose. Then deploy the 'redirect' code to the Heroku app and then turn maintenance mode off on Heroku. Visitors to the herokuapp.com address will then be redirected to the application running on the new URL wherever that may be.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds like a plan, do you have any suggestions on how the rack_rewrite might work?

Comment: See https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite - or simpler if it's an existing rails application but a before_filter in your application_controller.rb that does a redirect_to your new URL.

Comment: I thought of the before filter option but wasn't sure if a redirect would work to a different domain. I think using a before filter would probably be the best option :)

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Redirecting/redirect_to - it will work to an external domain.